# Automapper: warning MSB3817... must define a NeutralResourcesLanguageAttribute

Tags: c#, uwp, automapper

Getting this compile time warning with AutoMapper v6.0.2. warning MSB3817: The assembly "C:\Users....nuget\packages\AutoMapper\6.0.2\lib\netstandard1.3\AutoMapper.dll" does not have a NeutralResourcesLanguageAttribute on it. To be used in an app package, portable libraries must define a NeutralResourcesLanguageAttribute on their main assembly (ie, the one containing code, not a satellite assembly).

Is there anything I can do about this warning, or does AutoMapper need to add the neutral language to their assembly?

Thanks.